# JavaScript - how can I check if a string is part or equal to another string

Tags: javascript

Just to illustrate what I want to do I'll pase this sample code for example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function oc(a)
{
  var o = {};
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    o[a[i]]='';
  }
  return o;
}
if ( "Island" in oc(["Hello","Hello World","Have","Island"]) )
{
document.write("Yes");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case I get `Yes` on my page, but if I change the condition like:

> if ( "Isl" in oc(["Hello","Hello World","Have","Island"]) )

the function doesn't find match. What is the best way to perform such kind of check which will return true even if only part of the string match?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Javascript is not Python. I suggest you try to drop that "in" hack of yours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var str = 'hello world'
if (str.indexOf('lo') >= 0) {
    alert('jippy');
}
```

---

`indexOf()` returns the position where the value is found. If there is no match it returns `-1` so we need to check if the result is greater or equal to `0`.

Comment: Here is a useful reference for [`String.indexOf(str)` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: you could also use the `String .match()` method and check for `true`, but this is will run faster.

Comment: if you need case insensitivity, you can use `.toLowerCase()` on `str`, e.g. `if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf('lo')) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .test method from regexes.

```
var pattern = /Isl/;
pattern.test("Island"); // true
pattern.test("asdf"); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "helloo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core%5FJavaScript%5F1.5%5FReference/Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function inArray(str, array) 
{ 
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
  { 
    if (array[i].indexOf(str) >= 0)
        return true;
  } 
  return false;
} 
if ( inArray("Island", ["Hello","Hello World","Have","Island"] ) 
{ 
document.write("Yes"); 
} 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```